# Difficulty with `tableofcontents` and page-numbering

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, hyperref, page-numbering, document-classes

I'm writing my math thesis with Texmaker, but somehow my LaTeX codes fail to produce the PDF layout required by my school. Ideally, I'm hoping to achieve the following result:

> [image]

Please notice that this is just a drawing of the desired PDF page. I'm still working on it. In fact, what I have now is:

> [image]

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{CJKutf8,mathpazo,upgreek,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,mathtools,mathabx,physics}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{coro}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem*{thm*}{Theorem}
\newtheorem*{prop*}{Proposition}
\newtheorem*{coro*}{Corollary}
\newtheorem*{lem*}{Lemma}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{dfn}[thm]{Definition}
\newtheorem{rem}[thm]{Remark}
\newtheorem*{dfn*}{Definition}
\newtheorem*{rem*}{Remark}
\begin{document}
\includepdf{Thesis acceptance certificate.pdf}

\section*{Acknowledgements}
TBA

\newpage
\section*{Abstract in the official language}
TBA

\newpage
\section*{Abstract in English}
TBA

\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\section{Introduction}
TBA

\section{Preliminaries}
TBA

\section{Proof of the main result}
TBA

\section{Discussion}
TBA

\newpage
\section*{Appendix A. The Gauss equation}
TBA

\newpage
\section*{Appendix B. Weak solution}
TBA

\newpage
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{MTW} Charles W. Misner, Kip S. Thorne, and John Archibald Wheeler,
\textit{Gravitation}, Princeton University Press, Princeton and Oxford, 2017. Reprint of the 1973 original.

\bibitem{Wald84} Robert M. Wald,
\textit{General relativity}, The University of Chicago Press, Chicago and London, 1984.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

I was wondering if there is a way to include the missing pages in the contents and make the front matter have page numbers in Roman numerals. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Since your school has a required format for LaTeX documents, do they have a template or document class that you can use?

Comment: @bonk Thank you for commenting, but my school actually has a required format for a **PDF** document. The administration do not know about LaTeX and do not provide a LaTeX template. Students in other areas of study may write their theses with Microsoft Word, but I don't think it's a good platform for a math thesis.

Comment: Seeing all this newpages, are you sure that article is the right class? With book you would have chapters and also \frontmatter and \mainmatter

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you. I did consider to use the `book` class, but my thesis is short (like, 20 pages), so I prefer to use "Section" instead of "Chapter". This is why I eventually chose to use the `article` class.

Comment: Roman numbers in a 20 pages thesis are nonsense.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - I guess that if the OP's university requires roman page numbers in the front matter part of a thesis, then that's what the OP has to produce... Of course, this doesn't address the question whether the university's requirements make sense... :-)

Comment: Mico is right. My school does ask the students to use Roman page numbers in the front matter and use Arabic page numbers in the body, which is why the desired PDF page goes like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your best bet is to switch to the `book` document class, to make use of some of its structuring machinery (such as the `\frontmatter`, `\mainmatter`, and `\backmatter` commands) and, if and when needed, to adapt some of the features of the `book` class to make them conform to your institution's formatting requirements.

The following may be a good start in this direction.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany,demo]{book} % remove 'demo' option in real doc.
\usepackage[hmargin=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,mathtools,mathabx,physics}
\let\widering\relax% <-- new

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath} % <-- new, instead of 'mathptmx'
\usepackage{CJKutf8,upgreek,mathrsfs}

\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{0} % show only chapter-level entries

%\numberwithin{equation}{section} % <-- not needed

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{coro}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem*{thm*}{Theorem}
\newtheorem*{prop*}{Proposition}
\newtheorem*{coro*}{Corollary}
\newtheorem*{lem*}{Lemma}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{dfn}[thm]{Definition}
\newtheorem{rem}[thm]{Remark}
\newtheorem*{dfn*}{Definition}
\newtheorem*{rem*}{Remark}

% new:
\usepackage{lipsum} % filler text
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} % create a toc entry for bibliography

\usepackage{etoolbox} % for '\patchcmd' macro
\makeatletter % needed for handling of macro names that contain '@'
\renewcommand{\@chapapp}{}
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\thechapter}{\thechapter\quad}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\par\nobreak}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\vskip 20\p@}{}{}{}
\makeatletter


\begin{document}

\pagestyle{plain} % page numbers at bottom of page, no headers

\frontmatter % roman page numbers, unnumbered chapters

\includepdf[width=\textwidth]{Thesis acceptance certificate}

\chapter{Acknowledgements}
\lipsum[1-4] % filler text

\chapter{Abstract in the official language}
\lipsum[1-4]

\chapter{Abstract in English}
\lipsum[1-4]

\tableofcontents


\mainmatter % arabic page numbers, numbered chapters


\chapter{Introduction}

\begin{equation} 1+1=2 \end{equation}
\lipsum[1-14]


\chapter{Preliminaries}

\begin{equation} 1+1=2 \end{equation}
\lipsum[1-14]


\chapter{Proof of the main result}

\begin{equation} 1+1=2 \end{equation}
\lipsum[1-14]


\chapter{Discussion}

\begin{equation} 1+1=2 \end{equation}
\lipsum[1-14]


\backmatter % switch to unnumbered chapters, keep arabic page numbers

\chapter{Appendix A. The Gauss equation}

\setcounter{equation}{0}
\setcounter{section}{0}
\renewcommand\theequation{A.\arabic{equation}}
\renewcommand\thesection{A.\arabic{section}}

\begin{equation} 1+1=2 \end{equation}
\lipsum[1-14]


\chapter{Appendix B. Weak solution}

\setcounter{equation}{0}
\setcounter{section}{0}
\renewcommand\theequation{B.\arabic{equation}}
\renewcommand\thesection{B.\arabic{section}}

\begin{equation} 1+1=2 \end{equation}
\lipsum[1-14]



\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{MTW} Charles W. Misner, Kip S. Thorne, and John Archibald Wheeler,
\textit{Gravitation}, Princeton University Press, Princeton and Oxford, 2017. Reprint of the 1973 original.

\bibitem{Wald84} Robert M. Wald,
\textit{General relativity}, The University of Chicago Press, Chicago and London, 1984.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. I did consider to use the `book` class, but my thesis is short (like, 20 pages), so I prefer to use "Section" instead of "Chapter". This is why I eventually chose to use the `article` class.

Comment: @Boar - I don't understand your apparent aversion to using the `book` document class. Having a short document is not a compelling reason for not using the `book` class.

Comment: Sorry, in the beginning, I was afraid there might be a possibility of displaying the word "Chapter" because my thesis is really only a few pages. But after trying your sample codes, I realized that my concern is not going to happen: I do not see any "Chapter" displayed in the document. Thank you so much, but I have another concern: how do I make the certificate page go into *Contents* without adding a chapter title in the document? To be precise, I'm thinking about creating a chapter to include a picture file of the certificate instead of a PDF one, but that gets me an unwanted chapter title.

Comment: @Boar - Regarding your additional concern: I would suggest you add the instruction `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Thesis acceptance certificate}` immediately before the `\includepdf` instruction. Doing so creates an entry in the toc file (which contains the material shown when `\tableofcontents` is run).

Comment: @Boar - Incidentally, if the font size for chapter-level headers is too large for your taste, I would suggest you run the instructions `\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\huge}{\LARGE}{}{}` and 
`\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\Huge}{\LARGE}{}{}` immediately after `\renewcommand{\@chapapp}{}`. I wouldn't use `\Large`, as that would be the same as for `section`-level headers.

Comment: `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Thesis acceptance certificate}` does work; indeed, now I can see the corresponding hyperlink in *Contents*. But the code does not produce the page number of i on the certificate page. May I ask if there is a way to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: @Boar - I had assumed so far that the file loaded by the `\includepage` directive contains a single page and that there's a page number -- specifically, `i`-- at the bottom of that page. This assumption would appear to be only partially correct. If you can't insert a page number into to the one-page pdf file, don't use `\includepdf`. Instead, (a) load the `graphicx` package and (b) replace `\includepdf{Thesis acceptance certificate}` with `\bgroup \centering \includegraphics[height=\textheight, width=\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{Thesis acceptance certificate} \egroup`.

Comment: Sorry, that's really my fault. I should have told you that the one-page certificate PDF does not contain a page number. Now it sounds like if I had included a page number in the certificate somehow, then there would be nothing to be fixed and your code would work perfectly fine.

Comment: Sorry, may I ask one last question? I noticed that there is a redundant empty page numbered vi between *Contents* (numbered v) and *Introduction* (numbered 1). Why is that? Is it possible to get rid of that empty page? Thank you.

Comment: @Boar - I suggest you insert the instruction `\patchcmd{\mainmatter}{\cleardoublepage}{\clearpage}{}{}` in the preamble (*after* loading `etoolbox`).

Comment: @Boar - I just noticed a (hopefully minor) mistake in my code: I had incorrectly replaced `\usepackage{mathptmx}` with `\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}`, which loads a Palatino clone. It should have been `\let\widebar\relax \usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}`, which loads a Times Roman clone that's comparable to the font in `mathptmx`. My apologies.

Comment: @Boar - One more remark: If your bibliography has fewer than ten entries, you should replace `\begin{thebibliography}{99}` with `\begin{thebibliography}{9}`.

Comment: Thank you, Mico. Your prompt assistance was really crucial, and without it, I would not have been able to resolve these issues within the limited time frame. Thank you so much.